# Dynamic SQL calling another stored procedure in Teradata

Tags: stored-procedures, teradata, teradatasql

I've seen in the help guides that you cannot use a call statement in a teradata dynamic sql statement without output parameter.

I assume this implies I can, If the proc has an output parameter.

has anyone done this?

Scenario -

I have a table that at some point I'll expand out in terms of fields for logic on when things should run, and this table is managed elsewhere -

```
    CREATE TABLE DB.SP_Test 
(

    ProcName    VARCHAR(250)
    ,ProcRun     VARCHAR(1)
);
```

now I added chrTest as an output however, I am still getting an error on run (no compile error)

The error :-
SQL_State   SQL_Exception
T7689       Invalid dynamic SQL statement.

```
REPLACE PROCEDURE DB.Test_Control (OUT chrTest VARCHAR(250) )

SQL SECURITY INVOKER 

LMain: 
BEGIN
DECLARE sqlProcRun     VARCHAR(20000);

DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER
    FOR SqlException
    BEGIN
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    DECLARE strExceptionText VARCHAR(250);
   
    GET DIAGNOSTICS EXCEPTION 1 strExceptionText = Message_Text;  
    
    INSERT INTO DB.PROC_ERROR VALUES 
    (
        'Test_Control'
        ,:SqlState
        ,strExceptionText
        ,Current_Timestamp
    )
    ;
    END;    
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
SET sqlProcRun ='';
    
    L0: 
    FOR procs_run_cursor AS select_list

    CURSOR FOR    
        SELECT Trim(ProcName) AS ProcName
        FROM   DB.SP_Test 

    DO  
       /*creating a lost of call statements to run*/
       SET sqlProcRun = sqlProcRun ||'CALL DB.'||procs_run_cursor.ProcName|| '();';
    END FOR L0;
    
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sqlProcRun;

END;
```

Comment: I've also tried to replace EXECUTE IMMEDIATE TO CALL DBC.SysExecSql(sqlProcRun); no bingo

Comment: SPs don't support CALL in Dynamic SQL. Maybe you misread, the mix SPs and Embedded SQL in a single manual is confusing.

Comment: @dnoeth - thanks; Any thoughts on a way to achieve a similar sort of thing without saving the sql into character fields?

Comment: Within an SP?  No. Btw, your cursor looks like you want to execute multiple CALLs as a multi statement -> not allowed, too, only nested CALLs.

Comment: An external stored procedure (e.g. in Java) can issue dynamic CALLs. External SPs are covered in a separate manual along with information about external UDFs.

Comment: BTW - the section of the documentation I think you were referring to talks about not being able to use EXECUTE IMMEDIATE / SysExecSQL if the dynamic statement returns a result set (rows); you would need to use a dynamic cursor for those instead. That's something entirely different from OUT parameters.